# Can large titles be maintain when the user scrolls within a navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've set `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` and I'm wondering is there any option that prevents the default action of scrolling the title into the main Navigation bar when the user scrolls.

I can't see anything obvious within the nav bar properties but wanted to ask first before I build my own view that I will pin to the bottom of the nav bar.

Thanks

Comment: It's a fair question; I don't think downvoting it was right. As you rightly suspect, there's no "option" for this: how a navigation controller treats large titles in response to scrolling is up to the navigation controller.

Comment: Yea, I don't think this is possible. An alternative would be to add a custom UIView and imitate the Large Title display on the top of your view controller.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. Asked on a whim as I wanted to double check before I added a custom view. Would be a nice option to have though. My client loves the large titles now he's seen them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved my issue with a simple workaround that works great. Instead of adding my `UIScrollView` to the `UIViewController.view` and constraining it to the `view.topAnchor`, I've added a `UIView` [named staticView] to my UIViewController. Constraining that staticView to the `view.topAnchor` and then constraining `UIScrollView` to my static view prevents the largeTitles from being reduced, while still allowing the user to scroll.

When a `UIScrollView` is constrained to the topAnchor the OS reduces the nav bars large titles to their default size as the user scrolls. Having the scroll view pinned to the static view interrupts this behaviour and the large titles remain.